# How to find the maximum of occurrences in a row in several text columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, frequency

I have a row with 4 columns. Each column has text. I need to find the text which occurs the most, hand have the number of times it appears.

Example input:

```
c1  |c2  |c3  |c4 
----+----+----+----
AAA |BBB |CCC |AAA
DDD |BBB |DDD |AAA
AAA |BBB |AAA |AAA
```

Expected Output

```
r1  |r2
----+---
AAA |2
DDD |2
AAA |3
```

I tried doing something with case but it gets too complicated and many errors while trying to do it this way.

Answer (score 2):

You can unpivot the columns and then count the number of occurrences.

```
select u.*
from the_table
  cross join lateral (
      select val, count(*) as num
      from (values (c1),(c2),(c3),(c4) ) as x(val)
      group by val
      order by count(*) desc
      limit 1
  ) as u
```

The `from (values (c1),(c2),(c3),(c4)) as x(val)` turns the columns into rows, and the outer query then groups and counts them. `order by count(*) desc limit 1` then returns the row with the highest count.

Another option is to convert the entire row to a JSON value, then unnest that JSON to key/values. This is more flexible because it doesn't require spelling out all columns:

```
select u.*
from the_table t
  cross join lateral (
      select val, count(*) as num
      from jsonb_each_text(to_jsonb(t)) as x(col,val)
      group by val
      order by count(*) desc
      limit 1
  ) as u
;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=16d3d9234c7ee6aae7111d65fb4fd7f3)

Comment: extraordinarily remarkable

Comment: Seems great. It is possible to make it work when you have extra columns c5, c6, c7 which are other kind of datat, not to be taken into account in this process, but just passed to the outpout also? And what if you have about 22k lines ? it is a problem to have many lines ?